# JQuery : Add row after the third row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string  as 'new row'.I have a table which as 5 rows.I want to add this string after the third row of my table.How i do this using jQuery or javasript.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) for this

```
$("#yourtableid tr:eq(2)").after("<tr><td>new row</td></tr>");
```